# How to add a config.js file into nwjs install directory?

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I use node-webkit-builder to package my nwjs application.
Since the program running directory path is not same as the install directory path( the running directory path is like this: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\nw7388_7201 ). I don't know how to add my config.js file in the install directory, and read it in my nwjs app.

Best regards.

Comment: What is the purpose of your config.js?

Comment: Users could use this config.js to config some app features. like config the opening url (an url for an iframe in the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/App#datapath

This is common folder for application data. With `gui.App.dataPath` you always know where is this folder.

If you need get know where is your executable lives, try:

```
var path = require('path');
var nwPath = process.execPath;
var nwDir = path.dirname(nwPath);
```

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1197

Comment: I need to get the installing path where the nw.exe in. :)